# virtualy create pages .php script

Tags: php

hopefully someone here will find the answer to this:

Im looking to have a php code that will generate virtual pages for each city in USA, there are about 32,000 cities so to manually create those pages is nearly impossible, that's why I need a script that will create page virtually for example what I mean take a look here :
http://www.tvbydirect.com/directv-deal/

as you can see in the bottom page there are all the states and then when you click there are all the cities in that state, now notice that the page stays the same (header, contact form, footer) but the content is the same just the city name is changed, also in the meta tags.

what line of code, or script can/will do that ?

Comment: You mean like, one city.php and return a custom output depending on a Parameter in the address bar?http://example.com/city.php?city=Atlanta

Comment: I doubt this is what you really want to do unless you're generating HTML files.  Why not use one page and pass the city to that? Like `showcity.php?city=Chicago`

Comment: this is exactly what I want, to have in index.php link lists of all cities and the php script pulls them according to the link and modify the $cityname in content accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP acts as a dynamic web framework, there would be need to create *static* pages, as they can be within the dynamic form.

What you should do is generate a database with the required information and then use PHP To display different data depending on the environment its being called from.

For example, if you had the following web adress:

```
http://somesite.com/places/usa/washington
```

yo uwould then use the 2 variables `usa` and `washington` and then check the database for the required information.

```
 SELECT information FROM palces WHERE country='usa' AND and city='washington'
```

And then the information returned from the database would be printed in a custom template.

Comment: For this I would need a db with all cities in it and then pull them according to the link? then this would defiantly work

Comment: @Jack_R, Where do you supposed you get the list of cities to generate the static pages from?

Comment: @Clement Herreman - Thanks :( :)  

@RobertPitt I knew I need to use a file .xml or .xls to transfer to mysql so I could pull the info. but I assumed maybe someone has an easier way since there are so many cities

Comment: I would not advise this way if I didn't believe it to be a better solution, this is the way the most developers would accomplish this, XML File would be ported into a database, and then the dynamic pages would be produced from there.